# how to remove Carriage return at the end of the text box

Tags: vba

I want to remove extra carriage return at end of the text field. I used the following code but it removed it removed carriage return in the middle of the text. I need to remove at the end which is added while pressing return key

Text50.Text = Replace(Text50.Text, vbCrLf, "")

Text50.Text = RTrim(Text50.Text)

Pls suggest me

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there always is a vbcrlf at the end of the textbox, you can use this:

```
left(Text50.Text ,len(Text50.Text)-2)
```

Note that the length of vbcrlf is 2, since it is considered 2 characters: carrige return and line feed.

If you are unsure if the last character is vbcrlf or not, you can use this method:

```
If Right(Text50.Text, 2) = vbCrLf Then
  Text50.Text = Left(Text50.Text, Len(Text50.Text) - 2)
Else
  Text50.Text = Text50.Text
End If
```